# Worklight Mobile Browser Simulator issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-mbs

The `Mobile Browser Simulator` in my [`Worklight v6.1`](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=AN&subtype=CA&htmlfid=897/ENUS213-390&appname=USN&ce=ISM0056&ct=swg&cmp=ibmsocial&cm=h&cr=crossbrand&ccy=us) installation will not launch.  I am on Windows 7, with only 1 other app configured for the Worklight Server.  The server will not start as long as the MBS is in `server.xml`.  If I comment out MBS the server will start but then I have no MBS.  Is there a way to reinstall the MBS only?  The error is a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I set "Never publish automatically," and as soon as I click the Start button in the Servers view I get

```
' Publishing to Worklight Development Server...' has encountered a problem.  Publishing failed
```

The details are

```
   Publishing failed
      Publish _MobileBrowserSimulator
         OK
         Publish _MobileBrowserSimulator failed.
         java.lang.NullPointerException
         Publish of application _MobileBrowserSimulator failed.
      Publish MobileEnterprise
```

Any ideas how I can recover this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not modify any publish settings, as the development server relies on these. The MBS must be able to be published, otherwise of course you will not have the preview abilities in Worklight Console.

Try starting Eclipse with a fresh new workspace.
Create a new project and application (don't add any environments just yet). Start the server, run the app on the server, see if everything passes OK. If yes, carry on...

---

As for "re-installing" the MBS,

One thing you can try to do is to delete the "Worklight Development Server" project from the Project Explorer view in Eclipse and then re-start Eclipse. This process will re-generate all server entities, including the MBS.

Comment: I turned off publishing cause I thought it would help but I had the problem already.  So I deleted the WL Dev Svr project entirely from the Project Explorer & restarted but the Dev Server project is still gone.  I tried starting the Worklight Server from the Servers view.  This time it asked me if I wanted to remove the MBS from the server because its resources were gone.  I did the & WL Server started!  But now I'm missing the MBS.
Everything does start in a separate workspace.  Do I need to export/import all my projects or is there a way to simply reinstall the MBS in this workspace? - Thx

Comment: But...!  Even though the Worklight Development Server project no longer shows up in the Project Explorer view the Mobile Browser Simulator runs now when the WL Server starts!  So Idan you were right.  Thank you.   (...Now if only there's a way to get the Dev Server project to show up in the Project Explorer again...?)